# How to read multiple block data from Sony Felica NFC card?

Tags: android, nfc, sony

To read data from Sony Felica NFC card I am sending below shown command from android:

```
 byte[] command = new byte[]{
                    (byte)0x10, //Length
                    (byte)0x06, //Command Code
                    (byte)0x01, (byte)0x2e, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x39, (byte)0x9c, (byte)0xc9, (byte)0x3a, (byte)0x51, // IDm
                    (byte)0x01,//Number of service
                    (byte)0x09, (byte)0x00,//Service code
                    (byte)0x01,//Number of block
                    (byte)0x80,  (byte)0x03 // Block Data
            };
```

Through **transceive()** function

```
byte[] responsePacket = nfc.transceive(command);
```

I am getting data of block 3 in response.

But I want to read multiple block data from the card with one command. Like I want to read block data of block 3 and 4 at a time. Couldn't achieve this.
Any reference should be helpful too.